# Pass values to a div and prepend it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I have a div :

```
<div id="message">
  <p>Message: </p>
  <p><%= message.value %></p>
  <p>User: </p>
  <p><%= message.user %></p>
</div>
```

and a coffescript with ActionCable functionality

```
App.notification = App.cable.subscriptions.create "MessageChannel",
   received: (data) ->
   $('#messages').prepend ?
```

I want to pass data values (data.message and data.user) to the div and prepend it   to the div with "messages" id. Is there a way to do it ?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="messages"></div>

<div id="message">
  <p>Message: </p>
  <p id="pMessage"></p>
  <p>User: </p>
  <p id="pUser"></p>    
</div>

function addMessage(data){
    $("#pMessage").text(data.message);
    $("#pUser").text(data.user);
    $("#message").appendTo($("#messages"));
}
```

Comment: I am aware of this solution. I would like to pass the data values to the div. Thank you very much for your comment

Comment: Oh ok. I don't understand what you mean by 'pass the values' to the div. You want to set attributes of the div with the values, like $("#messages").attr("data-message", data.message); ?  Or do you mean you want to replace "<%= message.value %>" with the value of data.message, like string/token replacement?

Comment: I want to replace f.ex "<%= message.value %>"  with data.message and then prepend the changeg div to "messages" div

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm not very familiar with CoffeeScript. I assumed you could also use jQuery which is what I was using. I put it in a javascript function just to group the actions together but I would guess there's some way to port the same activity to a coffeescript version.

Comment: Ah I see. I was approaching this question purely from a javascript standpoint. Since it's getting specifically into the ruby and coffeescript aspects of your question I'll have to defer to someone else. Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with those pieces.